# Installing WebExtension for Firefox from GPO

Tags: firefox

I would like to install a WebExtension for Firefox for multiple computers.

I have tried adding in regedit a key named with the uuid of my WebExtension and the path to the xpi "...\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions{uuid}.xpi". The key is in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions\

I have then restarted Firefox but it does not ask to install the WebExtension or installed it.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install the extension. It should be present on your physical Drive. If you want to  a Web-extension for Firefox for multiple computers. You can try and create a batch file that automatically install extension on one click or you can simply use Dropbox across the computers and  Sync Your Profile Folder where Firefox files are present with that extension installed.

Answer (score 0):

The extension file (.xpi file) is present. It is located in "C:...\Mozilla Firefox\browser\". I have already created a .msi file to deploy it on multiple computers. The only thing left is that after restarting Firefox, it does not detect that I have set a key in regedit to install a new extension.